# Bigger/Medium images for Venues search app in foursquare

Tags: search, foursquare

The [venues API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) provides only the icon images. It does not provide bigger images for that venue. Is it possible to retrieve the bigger/Medium sized images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [venues/photos](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos) endpoint to get the photos for a venue. Refer to the [photos response](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo) documentation for information on how to turn the photos response into a photo URL. Photos are available in sizes up to 500x500px